# Compiling Microsoft's LoginAdmin.dll code without Visual Studio

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, compilation, impersonation

I'm trying to use some impersonation functions in a classic ASP page. I found a MS KB article at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/248187 which explains how to do this, but it requires compiling a DLL. Unfortunately, they expect the developer to have Visual Studio, which I do not have access to (nor do I want to). Could anyone tell me how I would do this with text editor and CLI? I'm getting lost around step 4.

Comment: You are aware you can get the express editions for free? http://www.microsoft.com/exPress/download/ so you surely have access to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in the article is in VB6, you will need a copy of VB6 to compile it.  Of course you can find examples of this sort of code in VB.NET as well.  Click [here](http://www.hagrin.com/forums/viewtopic.php?p=408) for an example.

This [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/380cz5k4(VS.80).aspx) will help you use the .NET frameworks VB compiler.

So it just a matter of placing the bits of source you want into .vb file and compiling as a library.  You need to ensure that you get all the COM visible stuff in there so you can call it from VBScript.